# Android POST запрос iii

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

Всем привет, нужна помощь с `POST` запросами. Вообщем, есть голосовой ассистент "Дуся". И в ней есть скрипт "А-я-яй чат бот". Вообщем это чат-бот с сервиса `iii.ru`. Посмотрел что он делает. Он отправляет `POST` запрос на сайт http://iiibot.azurewebsites.net/botv3.php . 
В теле запроса указаны: "`Text`" : "`$msg" "ClientID`" : "`$user_id`". 
Как я понял нужно отправлять запрос на сайт с указанием двух параметров. Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно сделать, чтобы оно работало.И можно ли вообще это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: retrofit, asynctask, okhttp - вам о чем-нибудь говорит? Зачем браться за сложности сразу, разберитесь для начала вообще с тем, что такое запросы, какие они бывают, чем различаются :)

Comment: Да говорит, просто нужно же поидее как-то правильно сформировать url, чтобы получить необходимый ответ.

Comment: вот видите, вы не понимаете, что такое пост-запрос и чем он отличается от других типов. Учите матчасть :)